# Placing image at the center of two DIVs at a time

Tags: jquery, html

I have two divs (with class names ca1 and ca2), I want to place image (veer.jpg) at the center of both divs by using jquery, I have succeeded in this but at a time I am able to place only one picture at the center, for example if I use jquery function for ca1 then this works fine but if at the same time I use jquery function for ca2 then it don't, now if I delete function for ca1 and now use jquery function for ca2 then this works fine. I am not able to use jquery function for two divs at a time. Can anybody help please.

My html page is as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hwcb.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="ca1"style="height:600px; width:600px; top:100px; left:400px; position:absolute; background:pink;">
<img class="c1"  src="veer.jpg" style="height:200px; position:absolute;" />
</div>
<div class="ca2"style="height:600px; width:400px; top:800px; left:400px;position:absolute; background:grey;">
<img class="c2"  src="veer.jpg" style="height:200px; position:absolute;" />
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.js page is as under:

```
$(document).ready(function(){function move_div(){window_width=$('.ca1').width();window_height=$('.ca1').height();obj_width=$('.c1').width();obj_height=$('.c1').height();$('.c1').css('top',(window_height/2)-(obj_height/2)).css('left', (window_width/2)-(obj_width/2));}move_div();$(div).resize(function(){move_div();});});

$(document).ready(function(){function move_div(){window_width=$('.ca2').width();window_height=$('.ca2').height();obj_width=$('.c2').width();obj_height=$('.c2').height();$('.c2').css('top',(window_height/2)-(obj_height/2)).css('left', (window_width/2)-(obj_width/2));}move_div();$(div).resize(function(){move_div();});});
```

Comment: can you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle...please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`$(div).resize(function(){move_div();});})`

try

`$('.ca1').resize(move_div)`

Now you are adding a handler for every div you have.

Comment: @user3811050 why would you choose this when jmore009's answer is so much better and less code lol

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this. For one, you only need to call `$(document).ready(function(){ });` once and wrap your functions in there.

Next you can should loop through a similar identifier. I would add a class to both `.ca1` and `.ca2` instead of targeting just a `div`. I added `.center` in my example:

```
<div class="center ca1"style="height:600px; width:600px; top:100px; left:400px; position:absolute; background:pink;">
    <img class="c1"  src="veer.jpg" style="height:200px; position:absolute;" />
</div>

<div class="center ca2"style="height:600px; width:400px; top:800px; left:400px;position:absolute; background:grey;">
   <img class="c2"  src="veer.jpg" style="height:200px; position:absolute;" />
</div>
```

Now you can loop through any container with a class of `.center` (so you can add as many of these as you want), pass `$(this)` and the `img` to your function and run this for multiple boxes:

```
    $(".center").each(function(){
       var box = $(this); //grab the container
       var img = $(this).find("img"); //grab it's img
       move_div(box, img); //pass to your function
    });
```

Then in your function you can replace the hard coded values with your variables:

```
function move_div(box, img){
    window_width=$(box).width();
    window_height=$(box).height();
    obj_width=$(img).width();
    obj_height=$(img).height();
    $(img).css({"top": ((window_height/2)-(obj_height/2))+"px", "left": ((window_width/2)-(obj_width/2))+"px" });
};
```

Also, you can chain css rules with `.css()` if you wrap them in `{}`, and use a `,` to separate them, so:

```
$('element').css({"top": ((window_height/2)-(obj_height/2))+"px", "left": ((window_width/2)-(obj_width/2))+"px" });
```

instead of:

```
$('element').css('top',(window_height/2)-(obj_height/2)).css('left', (window_width/2)-(obj_width/2));
```

You also had:

```
$(div).resize(function(){
    move_div();
})
```

But the variable `div` is not defined and there is no reason to fire this function on `resize` since you're using fixed widths and heights. If this used percentages and was responsive then it would serve a purpose to re-center the img on page resize. So you can remove that

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/o1us648u/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you use jQueryUI javascript

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).find(" img").position({
        of: $(this),
        my: 'center center',
        at: 'center center',
        collision: 'none none'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fp37hr6/5/